# TinyMCE in hidden DIV turns off when opened twice

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have an HTML page with a hidden DIV (a modal popup), which is shown through a button. This popup contains multiple TinyMCE editors, referred by a class.

My old problem was that the editors were "disabled" (I couldn't click and write within) when popup would open up. I solved thanks to other Stack Overflow's threads by calling init() method when popup is opening.

```
modal.onOpen = function() {
    editor.init({
        selector: '.editor',
        menubar: false
    });
};
```

That solved my problem, but only the first time the popup opens! Second time the problem is the same (editor "freezed").
So i tried to add a switch, to have the init() called only the first time

```
var isInit = false;    

modal.onOpen = function() {
    if (!isInit) {
        editor.init({
            selector: '.editor',
            menubar: false
            });
        isInit = true;
    }
}
```

but nothing changed..
Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved removing editors every time the popup is closed. Even though I don't like such solution so much, and I don't understand why the problem arises either. More hints are welcome

```
modal.onClose = function() {
    editor.remove(); /* destroy all editors istances */
};
```